# Confused over simple java syntax - Novice programmer

Tags: java, syntax

I'm fairly new to java. I'm reading up on it and learning as I go along. I was hoping somebody could explain something to me. I looked up the implementation of the java library file in question but it didn't really solve much.

Let me start with an example of code:

```
System.out.println();
```

From what I understand this calls a method in the System class -  println(). Whatever is in the parentheses are passed to the method as arguments (if that's the correct word for it). This I understand.

I also understand...

```
System.out.println(SomeMethod(SomeMethodAgain(x)));
```

.. this code returns a variable from "SomeMethodAgain(x) and passes it to "SomeMethod(), and then the results from SomeMethod() are then passed to the println() method.

But here's the question... I've seen a line of code that returns a variable of the "Dimension" type:

```
Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
```

...now I could understand the code if it was just Toolkit.getDefaultToolKit(). but then it has the extension ".getScreenSize". So how does this command work? Is there a method within a method?? (I didn't think that was possible)??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
```

is equivalent to:

```
Toolkit tmp = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
tmp.getScreenSize();
```

It's calling an *instance* method called `getScreenSize()` where the instance it's called on is the one returned from the *static* method `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()`.

(It's not actually returning the instance; it's returning a *reference* to the instance, but one thing at a time...)

Answer (score 3):

All this means is that `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()` returns **an object**. The object has a method called `getScreenSize()`.

Comment: Thank you. This explanation was easier to understand from the perspective of a beginnger

Answer (score 1):

You can chain your method calls.

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
```

return one Toolkit, that is then called `getScreenSize()` on. The value of this expression is the result of the last call.